# Loop to keep track of the global max observation?

Tags: r

Hello Stack overflow community,

I am trying to put together what seems a very simple loop idea but I cannot make it work yet.

I have the following data

```
            open    high    peak    
2005-01-07  26.80   27.10   26.62   
2005-01-14  26.60   26.86   26.04   
2005-01-21  26.03   26.35   25.64   
2005-01-28  25.76   26.65   25.64   
2005-02-04  26.35   26.52   26.10   
2005-02-11  26.27   26.34   25.81   
2005-02-18  25.93   26.12   25.40   
2005-02-25  25.25   25.49   25.15   
2005-03-04  25.22   25.48   25.13   
2005-03-11  25.17   25.79   25.06   
2005-03-18  25.08   25.24   24.28   
2005-03-24  24.35   24.47   23.96
```

What I want is to have another col called peak that has a 1 whenever a peak has formed an another 1 once another value after that peak surpasses that previous 1. In the above case it would be something like as follows:

```
            open    high    peak    
2005-01-07  26.80   27.10   NA  
2005-01-14  26.60   26.86   0   
2005-01-21  26.03   26.35   0   
2005-01-28  25.76   27.65   1   
2005-02-04  26.35   26.52   0   
2005-02-11  26.27   28.25   1   
2005-02-18  25.93   26.12   0   
2005-02-25  25.25   25.49   0   
2005-03-04  25.22   25.48   0   
2005-03-11  25.17   25.79   0   
2005-03-18  25.08   29.85   1   
2005-03-24  24.35   24.47   0
```

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(data2) ) { 
  data2$peak =  0
  if (data2$high[i] > data2$high[i-1]) { 
    data2$peak = 1 
    } 
}
```

However, this already doesn't work as I obtain the next error:

> Error in if (data$high[i] > data$high[i - 1]) { : 
>     argument is of length zero "

I am stalled here, but still I would have to include the part in which peak is only 1 again if the current obs is higher than the previous obs with a 1 assigned to it (last peak) and otherwise 0.

By the way, my data is an xts object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a loop by comparing the value of `high` with `cummax` of `high`.

```
df$peak <- +(df$high == cummax(df$high))

df
#           open high peak
#2005-01-07 26.8 27.1    1
#2005-01-14 26.6 26.9    0
#2005-01-21 26.0 26.4    0
#2005-01-28 25.8 27.6    1
#2005-02-04 26.4 26.5    0
#2005-02-11 26.3 28.2    1
#2005-02-18 25.9 26.1    0
#2005-02-25 25.2 25.5    0
#2005-03-04 25.2 25.5    0
#2005-03-11 25.2 25.8    0
#2005-03-18 25.1 29.9    1
#2005-03-24 24.4 24.5    0
```

For `xts` object you might need

```
df$peak <- as.integer(df$high == cummax(df$high))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(open = c(26.8, 26.6, 26.03, 25.76, 26.35, 26.27, 
25.93, 25.25, 25.22, 25.17, 25.08, 24.35), high = c(27.1, 26.86, 
26.35, 27.65, 26.52, 28.25, 26.12, 25.49, 25.48, 25.79, 29.85, 
24.47)), row.names = c("2005-01-07", "2005-01-14", "2005-01-21", 
"2005-01-28", "2005-02-04", "2005-02-11", "2005-02-18", "2005-02-25", 
"2005-03-04", "2005-03-11", "2005-03-18", "2005-03-24"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak! Your solution has made my code far more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake, you for got the index at peak

```
for (i in 2:nrow(data2) ) { 
  data2$peak[i] =  0
  if (data2$high[i] > data2$high[i-1]) { 
    data2$peak[i] = 1 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked as long as convert the object to data frame and then back to xts. Thank you!